# Why when using backgroundworker and progressBar and label im getting exceptions and wrong progress report?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First in form1 top:

```
FileInfo[] allfiles;
string mainDirectory;
```

Then in form1 constructor:

```
mainDirectory = @"c:\temp\screens7\";
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(mainDirectory);
allfiles = directory.GetFiles();
trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
trackBar1.Maximum = allfiles.Length;
```

Then button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (allfiles.Length > 1)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

And the backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateAvi.AviMovie(allfiles,backgroundWorker1);
        }
```

Progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label9.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label9.Text = allfiles[e.ProgressPercentage].FullName; }));

        }
```

Then in another class i have this loop in a method:

```
public static void AviMovie(FileInfo[] FileNames,BackgroundWorker bgw1)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(FileNames[0].FullName);
                AviManager aviManager =
                    new AviManager(@"c:\temp\new.avi", false);
                VideoStream aviStream =
                    aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bitmap);
                int count = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < FileNames.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (FileNames[n].Length > 0)
                    {
                        bitmap =
                           (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(FileNames[n].FullName);
                        aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
                        bitmap.Dispose();
                        count++;
                        int pctDone = count * 100 / FileNames.Length;
                        bgw1.ReportProgress(count);
                    }
                }
                aviManager.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                string t = "error";
            }
        }
```

Some changes i did:

1. In the new class in the method AviMovie i added the bgw1 variable. And the reportprogress was: ReportProgress(pctDown)
2. In form1 in the progress changed event it was:

   private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
       }

When it was like this the progressBar was getting to the end to 100%
But then i wanted to report and display on label9 the files names each file name from the AviMovie method in the new class.

First i did:

```
label9.Text = allfiles[e.ProgressPercentage].FullName;
```

Then later i added the Invoke.

Now the problem was that it never showed the right files its all the time stopped on file 101 out of 167.
And progressbar also stopped just a little before the end. 
And all this problems happened when i started to use the label9.

And when it was stop just a little before the end on file 101 after few seconds it throw exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
       HResult=-2146233086
       Message=Value of '101' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value
       Source=System.Windows.Forms
       ParamName=Value
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
            at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 292
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ProgressReporter(Object arg)
       InnerException:
```

This is strange since in the form1 constructor i set the progreaaBar1 maximum to the allfile.Lenght
And the minimum to 0. So i changed now in the form1 designer the progressBar1 to mnimum 0 and maximum 1000 i set it to 1000 just for the test.

When i set it in the designer to maximum 1000 it was getting to 167 like it was suppose to do but then in the end it throw another exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
       HResult=-2146233080
       Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
       Source=System.Windows.Forms
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
            at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 293
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ProgressReporter(Object arg)
       InnerException:
```

This is line 292 in form1 :

```
progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

This is line 293 in form1:

```
label9.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label9.Text = allfiles[e.ProgressPercentage].FullName; }));
```

Why i needed to change the progressBar1 maximum to 1000 in the designer if i changed it to allfiles.Lenght already in the constructor ? else it will stop at file 101 and throw the exception with mininmum and maximum.

What is the second exception ? And how can i fix all this label9 files names report ?
In the AviMovie method in the new class i tried in this line:

```
bgw1.ReportProgress(count);
```

To report the count then the variable n then the pctDone.
IN all cases it went only untill file 101 and throw the exception.

** Its a bit long post but its all connected tried to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Looks like your calculation is wrong - this is what error says, or is it?

Comment: Just debug your program. Put a breakpoint in the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` method and check what the values are. Check the `trackBar1.Maximum` value. Put a breakpoint where you initially set it, to make sure it gets set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are indexing FileInfo with some kind of percentage.  You will have to reverse this calculation to get the count to index the array properly.